# Dropdowns On Materialize.CSS Pulling Data Dynamically From Google Sheets

Tags: javascript, html, google-sheets, dropdown, materialize

I use Materialize.CSS elements which I added to a Google Sheets sidebar and my goal is to pull data  (dynamically changing names) from a Google Sheets tab to a dropdown in a sidebar.

So when the sidebar opens, the dropdown in the sidebar should immediately pull actual names from the sheet.

I cannot get this dropdown to work. What am I doing wrong?

```
    //dropdown from MaterializeCss.com
    <div class="input-field col s6">
    <select  class="icons browser-default" id="client"  onChange = "getNameText()">
    <option value="" disabled selected>Opdrachtgever</option>
    </select>
    </div>            
    </div>
```

```
    //get the text of selected option
    function getNameText() {
     
        var sel = document.getElementById('client');
        var nameText = sel.options[sel.selectedIndex].text;
        return nameText;
        
     }
```

```
    //events we do upon loading the sidebar
      document.addEventListener('DOMContentLoaded', function() {
           
          var elems = document.querySelectorAll('select');
          var timer = document.querySelectorAll('.timepicker');
          var datepick = document.querySelectorAll(".datepicker");
          var autocomplete = document.querySelectorAll(".autocomplete");

          M.Timepicker.init(timer, {twelveHour: false,showClearBtn: true,defaultTime:   '00:00'})
          M.Datepicker.init(datepick, {format:'dd mm yyyy', autoClose: true});
          M.FormSelect.init(elems);
          var options = handlers()
    
      });

      function handlers() {
  
          google.script.run.withSuccessHandler(populateWords).giveData(); //names from clients tab
          google.script.run.withFailureHandler(showError).giveData();
       
      }
```

```
       function populateWords(data){
           
          var selectTag = document.getElementById("client") //select tag

          for (var k in data.Names) {        
              var thisID = k;
              var thisText = data.Names[k];
              var option = document.createElement("option"); //creating option        
              option.text = thisText
              option.value = thisID;
              selectTag.add(option);
          }  

        }
```

```
  //getting array of names
  function giveData() {

      var clients = [];
      var data = ss.getRangeByName("ClientsClientsNames")

     //loop names from sheet
     for (var i = 1; i < data.getValues().length; i++) {

     if (data.getCell(i+1, 1).isBlank() == false) {
         var name = data.getCell(i+1, 1).getValue()
         clients.push([name])
     }
     }
     var data = {

         Names: clients
     }
     Logger.log(data)
  
     return data;
  }
```

Comment: Would it be alright if you could provide us a sample data with dummy values. Also, on `populateWords(data)`, instead of using `selectTag.add(option);` can you try `selectTag.appendChild(option);` ?

Comment: @CenturyTuna thank you. appendChild(option) didn't work too. By sample data you mean clients names I use? It's just first and last names from a sheet. I thought maybe spaces could be a problem and tested it with cities names so it is one word but it didn't work too.

Comment: I found out that the code is working but something is blocking the dropdown options  in some occasions - it's irrelevant of the browser. I have it working in Firefox, another person - in Chrome, 3rd person has nothing working. But my other similar code works in Chrome. What can it be? Doesn't seem to be a browser cash issue, we tried on new Chrome too.